# Как повлиять на отображение элементов в Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, wpf

Например: у меня есть стандартная одноячеичная сетка и элемент управления внутри неё(допустим кнопка). Когда я перемещаю кнопку внутри ячейки - она отображается, а если перемещаю за пределы, то не отображается, ну или, соответственно, отображается частично. А сейчас она отображается неверно - когда я перемещаю эту кнопку, то она выходит за пределы ячейки и перекрывает другие элементы. Как мне этого избежать?

Comment: Что, никто не знает?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Silverlight у всех UIElement есть свойство Clip, использовать примерно так:

```
<Grid Width="200" Height="100">       
    <Grid.Clip>
        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0, 0, 200, 100"/>
    </Grid.Clip>
</Grid>
```

Что бы было проще с этим работать, можете написать behaviour, подробнее [тут](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2009/05/silverlight-cliptobounds-can-i-clip-it-yes-you-can/)

Comment: читайте лучше вопрос и комментарии

Comment: Это я к тому что ZIndex есть практически везде.

Если надо что бы кнопку обрезало, тогда ClipToBounds свойство тебе в помощь.

Comment: да это свойство есть в WPF но нет в Silverlight

Comment: Да, действительно, тогда попробуйте это:
http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2009/05/silverlight-cliptobounds-can-i-clip-it-yes-you-can/

Comment: спасибо, всю статью я не прочёл, но мне помогло свойство Clip, так что если исправите ваш ответ, то я поставлю зачтено

Comment: fixed

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать z-порядок. Все зависит от того, какой элемент вы добавили раньше. Также Вы можете вручную назначать z-индекс каждого элемента.

Comment: Там нет z-index'а, к тому же это просто помогло бы избежать перекрывания других элементов, а мне нужно чтобы он сам не отображался за пределами grid.

Comment: Z-индекс есть практически везде.

Comment: практически не в счёт http://www.tinypic.ru/?do=view&pic=20110428211148_394.png